# Gerrit - Push Annotated Tag - "failed to lock"

Tags: git, tags, gerrit

I have already tried several ways to push annotated tags on git into a repository handled by gerrit.
Created v0.1 with:

```
# git tag -a -m "message" v0.1
```

Then, when trying to push...

```
# git push --tags ssh://<user>@<gerrit server>/<project>
```

It always gives me a "failed to lock" error.

```
...
 ! [remote rejected] v0.1 -> v0.1 (failed to lock)
...
```

I've already configured the project access to add Push Annotated Tag into refs/tags/* reference.

Anything else I'm missing?

** Edited - adding results from gerrit gc and git fsck:

```
$ ssh -p 29418 <user>@<server> gerrit gc <project> --show-progress
collecting garbage for "<project>":
Pack refs:              100% (13/13)
Counting objects:       78
Finding sources:        100% (78/78)
Getting sizes:          100% (37/37)
Writing objects:        100% (78/78)
Selecting commits:      100% (7/7)
Building bitmaps:       100% (7/7)
Finding sources:        100% (23/23)
Getting sizes:          100% (14/14)
Compressing objects:    100% (3094/3094)
Writing objects:        100% (23/23)
Prune loose objects also found in pack files: 100% (24/24)
Prune loose, unreferenced objects: 100% (24/24)
```

Now git fsck:

```
$ git fsck --no-dangling
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (101/101), done.
```

Everything seems ok...
But, still, can't push annotated tags into gerrit.

Comment: Hi Daniel, apparently something is wrong with your repository... you could try to execute the Gerrit gc: ssh -p 29418 <user>@<gerrit server> gerrit gc <project> --show-progress, and the "git fsck": cd $GERRIT_SITE/git/<project>.git; git fsck --no-dangling. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, Marcelo! Thanks for the help... unfortunately didn't work. I've edited the post with the results from gerrit gc and git fsck.

Comment: Ok. Another possibility: I think you have in the server a tag named v0.1/<something>. I was able to reproduce the "failed to lock" error running the following commands: git tag -a -m "Test" foo/boo; git push origin tag foo/boo; git tag -d foo/boo; git tag -a -m "Test" foo; git push origin tag foo. Maybe the tag v0.1/<something> was created by mistake.

Comment: Yes, there was already a v0.1 created - for some reason my local repo is not synched with gerrit. I just tested creating a v0.2 over a different commit, pushed, and was able to pull the new tag from another local repository. But the first repo still complains of the error every time I try to push.

Well... will just remove this one and clone again, I guess everything should be fine now.

Thanks again, Avila!

Comment: Great! I post my comment as an answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have already in the server a tag named v0.1 or v0.1/. I was able to reproduce the "failed to lock" error running the following commands:

```
git tag -a -m "Test" foo/boo
git push origin tag foo/boo
git tag -d foo/boo
git tag -a -m "Test" foo
git push origin tag foo
```